# Error in iPhone SDK : GDB:Data formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-4.2

I try to run my iPhone app on the device, which has iOS 4.2.1 installed on it. I get the following error in xcode and the app crashes out after that.

**GDB:Data formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'.**

Here is a screenshot of that.

[image]

Comment: @Kevin Ballard :  I dont understand what exactly leads to this error. So, it would be great if you can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically occurs due to memory issues.Try running your app with instruments.